# If I measure the time it takes to execute a piece of code means I know how efficient the code is? JAVA

Tags: java, profiling, processing-efficiency, performance

Given the following pieces of code, which one is more efficient? The real method returnSomething() can also return 0 in reality so try/catch is needed.

```
//piece one
long sleepTime = 200;
try{ sleepTime /= returnSomething();}
catch(Exception e){sleepTime = 200;}
private int returnSomething(){
   return 1;
}

              //or

//piece two
long sleepTime = 200;
if(returnSomething() == 3){sleepTime = 67;}
else if(returnSomething() == 2){sleepTime = 100;}
else if(returnSomething() == 1){sleepTime = 200;}
private int returnSomething(){
   return 1;
}
```

I was trying to figure out which piece of code is more efficient in terms of processor usage, they bot do the same thing. I would like to know if the code I wrote for testing is fit for the purpose or whether I can do other kind of testing on the code. My findings show that piece 2 is 9 times more efficient (9 times less time to execute) even though it uses hard-code if statements and the last if statement is always executed.

Full working program

```
public class CodePerformanceTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        CodePerformanceTester tester = new CodePerformanceTester();
        tester.start();
    }

    public void start(){
       double start = System.currentTimeMillis();
       long sleepTime = 200;
       for(int i=0; i<10000000; i++){

           //uncoment here the two lines below
           //try{ sleepTime /= returnSomething();}
           //catch(Exception e){sleepTime = 200;}

           //coment the IF STATEMENTS when above code uncomented
           if(returnSomething() == 3){sleepTime = 67;}
           else if(returnSomething() == 2){sleepTime = 100;}
           else if(returnSomething() == 1){sleepTime = 200;}
       }
       double end = System.currentTimeMillis();
       System.out.println("Execution time for 10 million iteration was "+(end-start)+" ms.");
    }


    private int returnSomething(){
       return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The JVM is funny in that it can get more or less efficient depending on when, where and how code is called. It is best to use a profiler to see where bottle necks may be and to fix them. Barring that, you should have your methods called in a loop many times and should do this in several attempts and will need to swapping order of testing to see which is faster.

Comment: In your example, returnSomething does return 1 and it is very likely that the JVM will inline it and optimise the code accordingly...

Comment: micro benchmarks on a trivial piece of code, I think it's better to do `int ret=returnSomething();sleepTime =200/(ret==0?1:ret);`: return something in the temp var and only check for 0, it's more robust IMO

Comment: The first question to ask though is it worth the effort even trying to do this premature optimization? In all likelihood the answer is no, and in fact answering this important question is where profilers can truly shine.

Comment: for each piece of code i run the test ten times and every time I got a different result however, the result wasn't much far away from the previous so what I did was to add all the values up and then divide them by 10. By doing so I found that piece 2 is faster then than piece 1. What I'd like to know is whether the time to execute determine the code efficiency. I will try and use a profiler even if I never tried one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first piece is probably slower because dividing is more expensive than comparing values.